# SQL what does & in where clause mean?

Tags: sql, vb.net, date, ms-access

Is this code right:

```
"SELECT * FROM dataTable WHERE Datee Between '#" & textStartDate.Text & "# AND #" & textEndDate.Text & "#'"
```

What does that & mean and that # can someone tell me please
I am using vb and acess

Comment: If you are indeed using VB.NET (and not VB6/VBA) consider using [interpolated strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx). More importantly, to avoid SQL injection and to avoid having to format values to a SQL-compatible format, consider using parameters in your SQL statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ampersand "&" is used for concatenation.

Before

```
"SELECT * FROM dataTable WHERE Datee Between '#" & textStartDate.Text & "# AND #" & textEndDate.Text & "#'"
```

After

```
"SELECT * FROM dataTable WHERE Datee Between '#" & textStartDate.Text & "#' AND  '#" & textEndDate.Text & "#'"
```

The between statement was missing "'" quotes to enclose the date values.

**Edit**

How to add a wildcard to a non-date sql query.  This code has wild cards on both side of the variable.

```
...WHERE SomeField like  '*" & textWeAreSearchingFor & "*'"
```

Here are other examples on how to query date datetype.

```
...WHERE Datee >= '#" & textStartDate.Text & "#'"
```

OR

```
...WHERE Datee < '#" & textStartDate.Text & "#'"
```

Comment: Thanks A lot, can you tell me also, how to find the approx string from the table not the exact string?

Comment: Sure.  Where somecolumn like  '*" & variableForLike "*'

Comment: So how I can apply it to the Between ?

Comment: I am unable to test the most recent update to the main answer.  I used this article for guidance https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Examples-of-query-criteria-3197228c-8684-4552-ac03-aba746fb29d8

Comment: WHERE SomeField like  '*" & textStartDate.Text & "*'" results in an empty table but, but if i type the exact date it will return the correct value

Comment: Wild card comparisons are for use on non-date columns.

Comment: Date columns require more specific information like between or greater than this date or that date.

Comment: Still the question how I get an approx string not the exact ? lol

Comment: The "Like" statement will provide approximate string for non-date values.  The other two commands ">=" and "<" will give you various date ranges on date values.